# PHP Set Checkbox to Checked by Default Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I check a few other topics on this and none fit my senario of setting the checkbox to checked when the page loads.

The checkbox is not associated with a database, it is just for the code to see if it's checked or not. I know how to do this in HTML and PHP but I have a Wordpress plugin that has a checkbox that I need to be checked when the page loads.

Below is the code that displays the checkbox but I do not know what to add to make it set the checkbox to checked when the page loads:

```
$is_offers_enabled = get_post_meta($object_id, 'offers_for_woocommerce_enabled', true);
$is_offers_enabled = ($is_offers_enabled == 'yes') ? 'yes' : 'no';
     WCVendors_Pro_Form_Helper::input( apply_filters( 'ofwcv_offers_for_woocommerce_enabled', array( 
                    'id'        => 'offers_for_woocommerce_enabled',
                    'label'     => __( 'Enable Offers?', 'offers-for-woocommerce-wc-vendors' ), 
                    'type'      => 'checkbox',
                    'value'     => $is_offers_enabled,
                    'class'     => 'ofwcv_offers_for_woocommerce_enabled',
                    'wrapper_start' => '<div class="wcv-cols-group wcv-horizontal-gutters"><div class="all-50 small-100">', 
                    'wrapper_end'   =>  '</div>'
                    ) )
                );
```

Comment: Couldn't you add 'checked' => 'checked' to that array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to add `'checked => 'checked'` to the attribute list you are posting in your question.

```
WCVendors_Pro_Form_Helper::input( apply_filters( 'ofwcv_offers_for_woocommerce_enabled', array( 
    'id'        => 'offers_for_woocommerce_enabled', 
    'label'     => __( 'Enable Offers?', 'offers-for-woocommerce-wc-vendors' ), 
    'type'      => 'checkbox',
    'value'     => $is_offers_enabled,
    'class'     => 'ofwcv_offers_for_woocommerce_enabled',
    'wrapper_start' => '<div class="wcv-cols-group wcv-horizontal-gutters"><div class="all-50 small-100">', 
    'wrapper_end'   =>  '</div>',
    custom_attributes(
                  array('checked' => 'checked')
     )
) )
```

Comment: Did not work. I know this is the correct area that displays the checkbox cause if I change the label text it displays.

Comment: @Stretcher25 Perhaps it is picky about the ordering of the attributes and needs it to be listed before the wrappers?

Comment: @Stretcher25 You might also be able to do `'checked'=>true`

Comment: @Stretcher25 ok, i cant find ny good documentation on that class, but I found something about custom attributes. Perhaps thats a doable workaround: `'custom_attributes' => array( 'checked'=>'checked')`

Comment: That worked! How do I make this checkbox read-only? Thank you

Comment: @Stretcher25 try adding the readonly attribute to the custom attributes.

Comment: @Stretcher25 remember to mark accepted answers as correct and upvote all helpful comments and answers.